# ASP.NET Where to place .cs file with enums

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have a file with defined enums. Inside my project, I have a page in which I'd like to use these enums. Where exactly should I save enums file and how is it possible to use it? I tried using statement, but it seems that project doesn't know where is the file located.

Example of Enums.cs

```
namespace Enums
{
    // 
    [Flags]
    public enum TTDETAILS : long
    {
....
```

Comment: is this asp.net web site or web application project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this class file in the App_Code folder at your site root. If not present, add this folder your self. This is a special folder in ASP.NET system, which contains stand-alone classes, enums, structures etc.